# Private methods calling in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What my knowledge says about Ruby is that private methods cannot be called with explicit receiver even `self`.

```
 class Private
   private
   def private_method(c)
    puts '#{c}'
  end
 end

p = Private.new
p.instance_eval{ private_method("private method called") }
```

How does this work? We can call private method with `instance_eval`. Please explain

Comment: You don't see explicit receiver here, do you?

Comment: I am confused by your question. You say private methods can only be called without an explicit receiver. You call the private method without an explicit receiver. Then you are surprised that you can call a private method without an explicit receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `instance_eval` executes the block in the context of `p` (meaning, it is `self`) and the call to `private_method` now is a call with implicit receiver.

Answer (score 6):

Ruby allows you to do a lot of "nasty" things that break encapsulation or whichever other principle.

`instance_eval` runs the block with `self` being `p`. And you can obviously call private methods when you're in the instance. You can even define methods that way!

```
class A
end
a = A.new
a.instance_eval{def value; 5; end}
puts a.value # prints "5"
```

It's not the only way you can do this. `send` is also allowed to call private methods:

```
class A
  private
  def p
    5
  end
end
a = A.new
puts a.send(:p) # prints "5"
```

Comment: yeah, with ruby you can break all of the principles. Nothing is sacred. :)

Comment: I think `send` shouldn't be allowed to access the private methods. Everything can be called with send!

Comment: @mhaseeb: take a look at `public_send`.